# Azure App Service: what if the current instance count is higher than the selected?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

So I have a very specific question which I haven't found an answer to it (partially because I don't find a easy way to search on google for this).

Imagine I have an App Service that has one autoscale rule

** From 0700 to 0800 increase to specific count = 4

The question is what if at 0650 the instances went up to 6 because of unexpected demand. When it is 0700 will Azure decrease to 4 or keep 6?

I think the latter but wanted to know if anyone had any experience on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is what if at 0650 the instances went up to 6 because of unexpected demand. When it is 0700 will Azure decrease to 4 or keep 6?

**It will decrease to 4.**

As the article said, `Horizontal scaling`, also called scaling out and in, means adding or removing instances of a resource. The application continues running without interruption as new resources are provisioned. **If demand drops, the additional resources can be shut down cleanly and deallocated.**

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/auto-scaling).

Comment: and what if with 4 my cpu is very high? will it create new instances to cope?

Comment: If with 4 and your CPU is very high, it means that 4 instance could not meet your needs. I will autoscal to more instance to cope.

Comment: Indeed. My question was about if the demand is too high and the configuration was left there, what would happen...

Comment: Actually, you need to ensure the maximum and minimum values are different and have an adequate margin between them instead of setting specific instance number. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-autoscale-best-practices). When you demand high, it will reasonable allocate instance to meet its needs. Also, as you have asked, if your demand too high and the setting was not enough, it might collapse.